# Rest API and Axios Request

Tags: javascript, rest, nginx, axios

I've written this code:

```
doIt(evt) {
    axios.get('/book', {
        params: {
            id: 1
        }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

I want to get the book with id = 1

I'm using a server running in nginx.
I don't know how to receive this request in the server and how to send the response to my client.
Help me please.

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: @Momin can you help me ??

Comment: What is your backend server that is going to process this request? Are you using NodeJS or something?

Comment: i'm using nodejs

Answer (score 0):

When you have a JavaScript front end that consumes a REST API back end, you have programming logic at both ends.
On its own, nginx is typically used for server static files or reverse proxying - it doesn't have its own way of serving a REST API.

You would typically use a web framework with a database to do the back end logic of serving the API.  One example of this is Django with Django REST framework.

[Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04) is an example of how you might set up such a back end stack.  Many other web frameworks are available that can be set up with nginx and do a similar job.